# issue with iframe and tailwind

Tags: typescript, next.js, iframe, tailwind-css

My project is with NextJS and tailwind, the problem I have is this, I want to display a series of components in the iframe, but after doing this, the tailwind styles that I have given to them in the form of classes are not applied in the Chrome browser. It recognizes a series of styles that I gave in the form of a CDN, but it does not recognize the styles that I gave through tailwind.config.ts, but it does not recognize any styles in other browsers.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const IFrame = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState<any>();
  const [render, seRender] = useState<any>(false);
  const didMountRef = useRef(false);
  const container = ref?.contentDocument;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMountRef.current) {
      if (container) {
        container.dir = 'rtl';
        const script = container?.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://cdn.tailwindcss.com';
        container.body.style.fontFamily = 'IRANSans Regular, sans-serif';
        container.head.appendChild(script);
        seRender(true);
      }
    } else {
      didMountRef.current = true;
    }
  }, [ref]);
  return (
   
      <iframe
        id="iframe"
        title="iframe"
        ref={setRef}
        style={{ width: '100%' ,height:"1000px"}}>
        {container && createPortal(children, container?.body)}
      </iframe>
   
  );
};

export default IFrame‍‍‍
```